# Difference between admin.site.register and makemigrations in django

Tags: python, django, interface, admin

I'm beginner to django and got quite confused that what is the difference between register out models by admin.site.register and makemigrations in both cases we're mapping our tables to database, if i'm wrong kindly correct me.
thank you

Comment: No, you register something to the admin to make it accessible on the *admin* subsite. But this has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score 1):

They're not related at all.

`admin.site.register(MyModel)` just makes instances of that model editable via the admin page. Without it they won't appear on the admin.

`makemigrations` just auto-generates some Python files, inside the `migrations` directory of each app. These files are like a description, in Python code, of what changes you have made to your models. They do nothing in themselves, until you run `migrate`, which is the only command here which actually touches your database schema - it updates the schema so that it matches what's in your migration files.

Comment: so if i dont map my model/table to database then how will i be able to go through my table from admin page?

Comment: You won't. Always run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after making any changes to your models.

Comment: i wanna ask you that if i dont map my model through migrate command then will i be able to see my tables on admin page

Comment: No, because until you migrate there is no actual table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

`admin.site.register` : This line of code "create" an admin interface for you when excecuted. This interface is intended for admin users.

`makemigrations` : This is a command to "manage" the changes of your model/database.

Comment: so if i dont map my model/table to database then how will i be able to go through my table from admin page?